Возможна ли работа с ссылками в MelonLoader?
Я недавно хотел сделать для одной игры, сделанной на Unity что-то типа мода, хотел сделать Report систему, чтобы человек мог сам в любой момент пожаловаться на другого игрока и это мне бы передавалось на мой Discord сервер по Webhook. Проблема в том, что он не работает. Не совсем понятно как вообще работать с ссылками в MelonLoader. Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли это в принципе и как?
